# Kendoui with Angular - Cannot see grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I am trying to use kendo ui with angular, I have downloaded kendo.all.js and angular-kendo.js
I have created a simple controller

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'kendo.directives']);
testApp.controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope) {
$scope.name='Hello';

$scope.products = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Tennis Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Basket Balls', department: 'Sports', lastShipment: '10/02/2013' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Oil', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Filters', department: 'Auto', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Dresser', department: 'Home Furnishings', lastShipment: '10/01/2013' }
    ]
});
```

});

and added to the view

```
<div>
    <div kendo-grid k-data-source="products" k-selectable="'row'"
            k-pageable="{ 'refresh': true, 'pageSizes': true }"
            k-columns="[
{ 'field': 'name, 'title': 'Name''},
{ 'field': 'department', 'title': ''Department'},
{ 'field': 'lastShipment', 'title': 'Last Shipment' }
   ]"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

however when I am launching it , I am getting blank page with no errors

Comment: forgot to to add var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'kendo.directives']);

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?  @li-raz

Comment: Let's check list this... did you add the ng-app at the top?

Comment: did you include the scripts for kendo-grid directives?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'kendo.directives']);